# Generate numbers for given range in php

Tags: php

I need to generate a sequence number between 1 to 10. I tried `range` function

```
range(1, 10);
```

but it generates `1, 2, 3...10`.

My requirement is to generate `1.1, 1.2, 1.3...2.0, 2.1...,9.8, 9.9, 10`.

Anyone please help me to find this solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the third parameter - Steps: ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php))

```
print_r(range(1, 10, 0.1));
```

If you want to start from 1.1, change to `range(1.1, 10, 0.1)`

Answer (score 0):

Added a little modification to @Thamilan's answer as you want start from `1.1`

```
print_r( range(1.1, 10, 0.1) );
```

**Manual**

```
range ( $start , $end [, number $step = 1 ] );
```

Answer (score -2):

We can use range with 3 parameters.

```
print_r(range(1,10,0.1));
```

Here we can get slot 0.1 between 1 to 10. 
Change 0.1 to other if you want other Series.

Comment: why downvoted ?? may be its downvoted because i give same answer at the same time...  but it's not my fault